# How to paraphrase this paragraph

Tags: sentence-meaning

I want to paraphrase the below paragraph, but it doesn't make any sense to me! I mean I don't understand it! Here is [the document link.](http://read.pudn.com/downloads33/sourcecode/windows/system/106178/FDIS14443-3.pdf)

> Higher layer response indicating that the higher layer command is not
>   supported by the PICC within this context **is allowed** as long as the
>   PICC response meets the format described above.

I think it needs a `that` before the in bold words. Is that right?

Which meaning is right?

1- Higher layer response is allowed as long as the PICC response meets the format described above

or

2-  higher layer command is allowed as long as the PICC response meets the format described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nailed it.

Remove the words that tell us further about 'which' higher layer response, and the sentence will be easy to parse.

> Higher layer response *(indicating that the higher layer command is not supported by the PICC within this context)* is allowed as long as the PICC response meets the format described above.

If you fit in *that* there, it won't look natural.

Answer (score 2):

> Higher layer response indicating that the higher layer command is not
>   supported by the PICC within this context is allowed as long as the
>   PICC response meets the format described above.

Let us "dissect" your sentence and look at the possible intended meaning.

Let us look at the possible subject and try to add some punctuations:

1. **Higher layer response**`,` *indicating that the higher layer command is not supported by the PICC within this context*`,` is allowed as long as the PICC response meets the format described above.
2. **Higher layer response indicating that the higher layer command is not supported by the PICC within this context** is allowed as long as the PICC response meets the format described above.

Both are correct and there is no need for the word ***that***. It only depends on what the writer intended to convey. In the first example, a comma was included which was to support the subject **Higher layer response**, therefore it could mean:

1. **Higher layer response** is allowed as long as the PICC response meets the format described above.

or

2. **Higher layer response indicating that the higher layer command is not supported by the PICC within this context** is allowed as long
   as the PICC response meets the format described above.